# Pass object in Intent

Tags: java, android

I would like pass object with Intent:

```
public class First extends Activity implements Serializable {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button here = (Button) findViewById(R.id.here);

        here.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyClass.class);
                Test test = new Test();
                intent.putExtra("test", test);  
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

}

but this in line with intent.putExtra("test", test);   return me error:

> The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, Test)

How can i make it?

Comment: Iis the Test class Serializable?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I dont know. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class header of Test to this

```
public Test implements Parcelable ...
```

use the next examples and create the Test class to implemet the Parcelable correcly.
[Parcelable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable)
[Parcelable Android Developers SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)

and it should work.,

ok new Solution change it to

```
public Test implements Serializable ...
```

no need to implement anything

Comment: can you please update your answer with the implemented Test class.

Comment: not the Activity the Class Test himself please read the answer again. use Serializable

Comment: Update your code mate its not possible plus write down the Test Class.